# How to read data packets from particular ip address?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, tcp

I am new in network programming , I want to know about the exchanging of messages between two computers connected through LAN Connection.

Suppose my ip address is 192.168.1.98 and other computer's ip = 192.168.1.55

Then how can i send and receive messages between them.

How to connect , open and read packets and messages if i know the port and ip address of other machine.

II want this through c# .

Please help!

Answer (score 5):

SO is not a tutorial site. For your question you can search with Google for `tcp communication` and `c# tcp example`. First you need to learn how TCP works and how sockets are used. Then you will be able to handle a simple communication.

.net framework offer some help with [TcpListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=vs.110).aspx) and [TcpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which should suit your basic needs for communication.

This code samples are taken from previous pages.

**TcpListener:**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

class MyTcpListener
{
  public static void Main()
  { 
    TcpListener server=null;   
    try
    {
      // Set the TcpListener on port 13000.
      Int32 port = 13000;
      IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

      // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
      server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

      // Start listening for client requests.
      server.Start();

      // Buffer for reading data
      Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
      String data = null;

      // Enter the listening loop.
      while(true) 
      {
        Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");

        // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
        // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
        TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();            
        Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

        data = null;

        // Get a stream object for reading and writing
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        int i;

        // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
        while((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))!=0) 
        {   
          // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
          data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
          Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);

          // Process the data sent by the client.
          data = data.ToUpper();

          byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

          // Send back a response.
          stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
          Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", data);            
        }

        // Shutdown and end connection
        client.Close();
      }
    }
    catch(SocketException e)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
    }
    finally
    {
       // Stop listening for new clients.
       server.Stop();
    }


    Console.WriteLine("\nHit enter to continue...");
    Console.Read();
  }   
}
```

**TcpClient:**

```
static void Connect(String server, String message) 
{
  try 
  {
    // Create a TcpClient.
    // Note, for this client to work you need to have a TcpServer 
    // connected to the same address as specified by the server, port
    // combination.
    Int32 port = 13000;
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);

    // Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
    Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);         

    // Get a client stream for reading and writing.
   //  Stream stream = client.GetStream();

    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

    // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

    Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", message);         

    // Receive the TcpServer.response.

    // Buffer to store the response bytes.
    data = new Byte[256];

    // String to store the response ASCII representation.
    String responseData = String.Empty;

    // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
    Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
    Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);         

    // Close everything.
    stream.Close();         
    client.Close();         
  } 
  catch (ArgumentNullException e) 
  {
    Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException: {0}", e);
  } 
  catch (SocketException e) 
  {
    Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
  }

  Console.WriteLine("\n Press Enter to continue...");
  Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: If its not a tutorial site (you are correct it is not), then why did you answer with a tutorial?  Please do not answer bad questions, it just encourages them to ask more of the same.

Comment: Because I think is better to help in correcting the question and then to try to answer to the real issue the OP is having. Just saying that the question is not good do not help.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience but if am asking about the c# code then what is the problem?

Comment: @ManishJain SO is made to ask specific questions, after you tried to solve something, you have some code written by yourself and didn't succeed. It is not a place to ask for tutorials and opinions. (and it has nothing to do with the fact that you asked for C# code). Read [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to understand a little bit how SO works.